# Accumulo API: When Does a Scanner Initially Communicate With Accumulo?

Tags: java, accumulo

When a client application uses the Apache Accumulo API to query Accumulo using a Scanner object, at what point does the client initially communicate with Accumulo?

Example query pseudocode:

```
Authorizations authorizations = ...;
Connector connector = ...; // Use authorizations
Scanner scanner = connector.getScanner(..., "theTable", ...);

// Set one or more Ranges
scanner.setRange(new Range(...));

// Add one or more scan iterators
scanner.addScanIterator(...);

// scanner.fetchColumn(...); // Or fetchColumnFamily

// Get iterator
Iterator<Entry<Key, Value>> iterator = scanner.iterator();
```

In the pseudocode above, my hunch is that client code first reaches out to Accumulo either (1) when the Scanner object's iterator() method is invoked, or (2) when, on the Iterator object, some method like next() or hasNext() is invoked for the first time.

In this scenario, when does the first communication between the client and Accumulo take place?

Answer (score 2):

After stepping through the code, I believe I've found the answer.

The "default" concrete class that implements org.apache.accumulo.client.Scanner seems to be org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.ScannerImpl. *(As an aside, ScannerImpl's super-class is org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.ScannerOptions.)*

ScannerImpl's iterator() method constructs and returns a org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.ScannerIterator object.

One of the parameters of the ScannerIterator constructor is readAheadThreshold, a long. ScannerImpl sets this parameter to org.apache.accumulo.core.Constants.SCANNER_DEFAULT_READAHEAD_THRESHOLD (3).

The ScannerIterator constructor reads ahead only when the readAheadThreshold parameter is 0. Since ScannerImpl sets the parameter to 3, the constructor doesn't read ahead. Thus, ScannerImpl's iterator() method doesn't communicate with Accumulo.

ScannerIterator's next() and hasNext() methods reach out to Accumulo only when "necessary." For a newly constructed ScannerIterator, it would be "necessary" to communicate with Accumulo upon the first invocation of either next() or hasNext().

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: Creating an Accumulo Connector executes an RPC to Accumulo to validate the credentials that you provided. In your example, there would have been an RPC already by the time you created the Scanner.